# Simple node.js modification, how to determine if a variable is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gekko

Question is technically about Javascript (node.js), and specifically the [Gekko](https://gekko.wizb.it/docs/introduction/about_gekko.html) software, which is coded using it. I'm trying to do a really simple modification to one of it's trading strategies: [the MACD](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_average_convergence_divergence_macd). The files involved are:

The MACD configuration file: [gekko/config/strategies/MACD.toml](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/develop/config/strategies/MACD.toml)

```
short = 10
long = 21
signal = 9

[thresholds]
down = -0.025
up = 0.025
persistence = 1
```

The MACD indicator file: [gekko/strategies/indicators/MACD.js](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/develop/strategies/indicators/MACD.js)

```
// required indicators
var EMA = require('./EMA.js');

var Indicator = function(config) {
  this.input = 'price';
  this.diff = false;
  this.short = new EMA(config.short);
  this.long = new EMA(config.long);
  this.signal = new EMA(config.signal);
}

Indicator.prototype.update = function(price) {
  this.short.update(price);
  this.long.update(price);
  this.calculateEMAdiff();
  this.signal.update(this.diff);
  this.result = this.diff - this.signal.result;
}

Indicator.prototype.calculateEMAdiff = function() {
  var shortEMA = this.short.result;
  var longEMA = this.long.result;

  this.diff = shortEMA - longEMA;
}

module.exports = Indicator;
```

And finally, the file to modify, the MACD strategy: [gekko/strategies/MACD.js](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/develop/strategies/MACD.js)

```
/*

  MACD - DJM 31/12/2013

  (updated a couple of times since, check git history)

 */

// helpers
var _ = require('lodash');
var log = require('../core/log.js');

// let's create our own method
var method = {};

// prepare everything our method needs
method.init = function() {
  // keep state about the current trend
  // here, on every new candle we use this
  // state object to check if we need to
  // report it.
  this.trend = {
    direction: 'none',
    duration: 0,
    persisted: false,
    adviced: false
  };

  // how many candles do we need as a base
  // before we can start giving advice?
  this.requiredHistory = this.tradingAdvisor.historySize;

  // define the indicators we need
  this.addIndicator('macd', 'MACD', this.settings);
}

// what happens on every new candle?
method.update = function(candle) {
  // nothing!
}

// for debugging purposes: log the last calculated
// EMAs and diff.
method.log = function() {
  var digits = 8;
  var macd = this.indicators.macd;

  var diff = macd.diff;
  var signal = macd.signal.result;

  log.debug('calculated MACD properties for candle:');
  log.debug('\t', 'short:', macd.short.result.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'long:', macd.long.result.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'macd:', diff.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'signal:', signal.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'macdiff:', macd.result.toFixed(digits));
}

method.check = function() {
  var macddiff = this.indicators.macd.result;

  if(macddiff > this.settings.thresholds.up) {

    // new trend detected
    if(this.trend.direction !== 'up')
      // reset the state for the new trend
      this.trend = {
        duration: 0,
        persisted: false,
        direction: 'up',
        adviced: false
      };

    this.trend.duration++;

    log.debug('In uptrend since', this.trend.duration, 'candle(s)');

    if(this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence)
      this.trend.persisted = true;

    if(this.trend.persisted && !this.trend.adviced) {
      this.trend.adviced = true;
      this.advice('long');
    } else
      this.advice();

  } else if(macddiff < this.settings.thresholds.down) {

    // new trend detected
    if(this.trend.direction !== 'down')
      // reset the state for the new trend
      this.trend = {
        duration: 0,
        persisted: false,
        direction: 'down',
        adviced: false
      };

    this.trend.duration++;

    log.debug('In downtrend since', this.trend.duration, 'candle(s)');

    if(this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence)
      this.trend.persisted = true;

    if(this.trend.persisted && !this.trend.adviced) {
      this.trend.adviced = true;
      this.advice('short');
    } else
      this.advice();

  } else {

    log.debug('In no trend');

    // we're not in an up nor in a downtrend
    // but for now we ignore sideways trends
    //
    // read more @link:
    //
    // https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/171

    // this.trend = {
    //   direction: 'none',
    //   duration: 0,
    //   persisted: false,
    //   adviced: false
    // };

    this.advice();
  }
}

module.exports = method;
```

This MACD strategy is advising a buy when all of these conditions are true:

- macddiff **>** this.settings.thresholds.up
- this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence

And is advising a sell when the opposite conditions happens:

- macddiff **<** this.settings.thresholds.up
- this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence

Ok, the modifications I need are:

- One new buy condition: **When actual macddiff value is > than its immediately precedent value**
- One new sell condition: **When actual macddiff value is < than its immediately precedent value**

For example, assuming 15 min candle sticks:

```
2018/06/12 00:00        macddiff = 5.3452
2018/06/12 00:15        macddiff = 7.5891 ----> **BUY**, because 7.5891 > 5.3452
2018/06/12 00:30        macddiff = 8.4982
2018/06/12 00:45        macddiff = 10.4389
2018/06/12 01:00        macddiff = 4.2340 ----> **SELL**, because 4.2340 < 10.4389
2018/06/12 01:15        macddiff = -2.4902
2018/06/12 01:30        macddiff = -1.9049 ---> **BUY**, because -1.9049 > -2.490
```

How can this be done? Which modifications must be done to the [gekko/strategies/MACD.js](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/blob/develop/strategies/MACD.js) file? Please, provide a complete file with the full modifications.

---

[This another answer in the Gekko forum](https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/239) may be util, but... Unfortunately I can't understand it correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
  MACD - DJM 31/12/2013 LUCCHI 07/06/2018
  (updated a couple of times since, check git history)
 */

// helpers
var _ = require('lodash');
var log = require('../core/log.js');

// let's create our own method
var method = {};

// prepare everything our method needs
method.init = function() {
  // keep state about the current trend
  // here, on every new candle we use this
  // state object to check if we need to
  // report it.
  this.trend = {
    direction: 'none',
    duration: 0,
    persisted: false,
    adviced: false
  };

  // how many candles do we need as a base
  // before we can start giving advice?
  this.requiredHistory = this.tradingAdvisor.historySize;

  // define the indicators we need
  this.addIndicator('macd', 'MACD', this.settings);
}

// what happens on every new candle?
method.update = function(candle) {
  // nothing!
}

// for debugging purposes: log the last calculated
// EMAs and diff.
method.log = function() {
  var digits = 8;
  var macd = this.indicators.macd;

  var diff = macd.diff;
  var signal = macd.signal.result;

  log.debug('calculated MACD properties for candle:');
  log.debug('\t', 'short:', macd.short.result.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'long:', macd.long.result.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'macd:', diff.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'signal:', signal.toFixed(digits));
  log.debug('\t', 'macdiff:', macd.result.toFixed(digits));
}

var macddiffLastValue // ADDED THIS LINE recipient for last value

method.check = function() {
  var macddiff = this.indicators.macd.result;

  if(macddiff > macddiffLastValue) { // Modified Check

    // new trend detected
    if(this.trend.direction !== 'up')
      // reset the state for the new trend
      this.trend = {
        duration: 0,
        persisted: false,
        direction: 'up',
        adviced: false
      };

    this.trend.duration++;

    log.debug('In uptrend since', this.trend.duration, 'candle(s)');

    if(this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence)
      this.trend.persisted = true;

    if(this.trend.persisted && !this.trend.adviced) {
      this.trend.adviced = true;
      this.advice('long');
    } else
      this.advice();

  } else if(macddiff < this.settings.thresholds.down) {

    // new trend detected
    if(this.trend.direction !== 'down')
      // reset the state for the new trend
      this.trend = {
        duration: 0,
        persisted: false,
        direction: 'down',
        adviced: false
      };

    this.trend.duration++;

    log.debug('In downtrend since', this.trend.duration, 'candle(s)');

    if(this.trend.duration >= this.settings.thresholds.persistence)
      this.trend.persisted = true;

    if(this.trend.persisted && !this.trend.adviced) {
      this.trend.adviced = true;
      this.advice('short');
    } else
      this.advice();

  } else {

    log.debug('In no trend');

    // we're not in an up nor in a downtrend
    // but for now we ignore sideways trends
    //
    // read more @link:
    //
    // https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/171

    // this.trend = {
    //   direction: 'none',
    //   duration: 0,
    //   persisted: false,
    //   adviced: false
    // };

    this.advice();
  }
  macddiffLastValue = macddiff // ADDED THIS LINE keep last value
}

module.exports = method;
```

Comment: Thank you very much lucchi for your interest, time and help. Unfortunately, don't seems to work, I'm getting the same backtest result using your modification, than the normal MACD strategy. Also, short/sell strategy seems incomplete.

Comment: @vicmarto, as you can see in in the code, I had modified sell strategy check, following: "I want to modify this strategy", after "the opposite for short/sell". After looking at it, the check may make no sense I must admit. Try my edit with modified buy strategy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried your last code modification, buy don't seems I'm getting the expected results.

I have modified slightly my question for a better understanding. Please, take a look, I think it's much clearer now.